# Fitting / drawing a closed curve of a given length within given dimensions

Tags: recreational-mathematics, curves, geometric-topology

Fitting / drawing a closed curve of a given length within given dimensions.

I'm trying to fit / draw a given length of a closed curve within given dimensions.

**Example:** Curve **length=941mm**, **width=3mm**, and **height=5mm** and it must fit within the dimensions **x=250mm** **y=210mm**

I was thinking of creating a shape like this **(where it starts and ends at the same location and it doesn't crossover / intersect with itself**)

[image: img1]

[image: ani1]

Another thought I had was to start off with a circle with the correct length / circumference, width and height and have it re-configured in a way to fit the given dimensions without it intersecting or crossing over (think indenting a rubber band multiple times)

[image: img2]

What type mathematical category would this fall under and how can I go about solving / calculating this?

Comment: What type of problem are you trying to solve?  Does the software you are using tell you curve length as you draw?

Comment: The software I'm using does not tell me the curve length as I draw it but it will tell me the total length of the curve at the end. I'm not sure what type of problem you would call it. But I'm trying to fit / draw a given length of a closed loop curve within given dimensions (I guess a closed loop space filling curve problem?) Not really sure what you would call it. Something like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve but "curvier" (see animation above) and with a closed loop.